# Postgres ENOTFOUND error when connecting docker services to a docker database container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I can't get one of my containers (service) to connect to the postgres database container through docker. It seems to be complaining about using the wrong database...(I'm using node.js with the 'pg' and 'pg-promise' libraries.).

My postgres connection info

```
const pg = require('pg');
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();

var config = {
  user: 'root',
  password: 'myPassword',
  database: 'myDb',
  host: 'database',
  port: 5432
};
const db = pgp(config);
```

Error when docker attempts to connect to the database

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND database database:5432
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'database',
  host: 'database',
  port: 5432 }
```

I know that by default the container has the same hostname as the service name, but that didn't work (my service name is "database"). Anything I'm missing?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    build: My-App/
    depends_on:
      - 'database'
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'

  database:
    image: postgres:11.5
```

Comment: did you expose 5432 in your `database` container ?

Comment: I tried adding 'ports: "5432:5432"' under "database" in the docker-compose.yml file, but still didnt' work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I eventually found the answer, so I thought I'd share:

The reason Docker couldn't automatically connect to Postgres was because Postgres was still initializing (and not receiving connection requests while it booted up).

One solution I found was to artificially delay Docker's connection attempt (basically wait until Postgres is ready before attempting to connect).

EDIT: Docker-compose version 3 now has docs on how to control which containers start first: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/